# Find all (p,n) such that $n^{p-1}|(p-1)^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all prime number p and positive interger n, such that $$n^{p-1}|(p-1)^n+1$$

This is a problem related to Lifting-the-exponent lemma. What I have tried:

If $p=2$, $n=1$ or $n=2$.

If $p>2$, let q is one of the prime factors, then we have $q|(p-1)^n+1$, so $$q|(p-1)^{2n}-1$$.

Also we have $gcd(p-1,q)=1$. By Fermat's little theorem, we have $$q|(p-1)^{q-1}-1$$

So $q|(p-1)^{gcd(2n,q-1)}-1$.

I also find that $(p,n)=(3,3)$ meets the requirement, so I feel confused. I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%5E%7Bp-1%7D%5Cmid(p-1)%5En%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [NT problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1841274p12372660) and [Number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2037091p14389612), as well as the closely related [Number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1514412p9008779), [Find all pairs](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1738506p11295405), etc.

Comment: Whatever "LTE" means, please write it out in full instead of LTE (which only appears once). I don't recognize that abbreviation.

Comment: @KCd FYI, based on the context here where I've seen it previously used as such (and I've also used it myself, but only after first defining it), I'm quite certain that LTE stands [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma). Nonetheless, I agree that the OP should have made this explicit as there are, I'm sure, many people who are not familiar with that acronym.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I heard that lemma name earlier this year. Its description at your link has so many cases. I find it simpler to express it in terms of the $p$-adic absolute value: it shows how power functions affect $p$-adic distances for numbers near $1$: if $p$ is odd and $|a - 1|_p \leq 1/p$, then $|a^n - 1|_p = |a-1|_p|n|_p$ for all integers $n$, while if $|a - 1|_2 \leq 1/4$ then $|a^n - 1|_2 = |a-1|_2|n|_2$.  (If $a,b\not\equiv 0\bmod p$ and $a\equiv b \bmod p$, then $|a^n - b^n|_p = |(a/b)^n- 1|_p$.) For all $p$ these follow from the $p$-adic exponential being a $p$-adic isometry.

Comment: @KCd LTE is widely used in the (high-school) contest community, where most students  have not yet learned anything about valuation theory.

Comment: @BillDubuque do you have any sense of how old the name LTE is among contest enthusiasts?  I just came across a reference to it on the 6th page (p. 48) of a survey paper from 2003 on the solution of Catalan's conjecture, where it is called the *Rule of Lifting the Exponent*: see https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-01/S0273-0979-03-00993-5/S0273-0979-03-00993-5.pdf.  I knew this result before 2003, but I'd never heard a special name for it. I had read this paper when it came out, but later did not remember its name for the rule.

Comment: @KCd Sorry, no idea since I was never involved in any of those communities. I too am curious about the history of the name. I wouldn't be surprised if it originated in training materials, e.g. Titu Andreescu's many expositions, or perhaps in university team training notes, e.g. R. Stanley used to train MIT's team when I was there. I would check with Franz Lemmermeyer also. If perchance  you plan to augment your many superb expository articles with one on LTE that segues into valuation theory etc.  then that would surely be very helpful to many students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p=2$, $n=1$ or $n=2$.

If $p>2$, $(p-1)^n+1$ is odd, so $n$ is odd.

Let q be the smallest prime factor of n, we know that q is also odd.

Then we have $q \mid (p-1)^n+1$, so $q \mid (p-1)^{2n}-1$.

Also we have $gcd(p-1,q)=1$. By Fermat's little theorem, we have $$q \mid (p-1)^{q-1}-1$$

So $q \mid (p-1)^{gcd(2n,q-1)}-1$.

And $(p-1)^{gcd(2n,q-1)}-1=(p-1)^2-1=p(p-2)$

**Case 1:**

If $q\mid p-2$, by $n^{p-1}\mid (p-1)^{2n}-1$, we have $$(p-1)v_{q}(n)\leq v_{q}((p-1)^{2n}-1)=v_q(p-2)+v_{q}(2n)$$(by Lifting-the-exponent lemma)

So $(p-2)v_{p}(n)\leq v_{q}(p-2)$, which is a contradiction.

(This is because $v_{p}(n)=v_{p}(2n)$, $v_{q}(k)\leq k$ for $k\geq q>2$)

**Case 2:**

If $q \mid p$, we have $p=q$.

We have $$(p-1)v_{p}(n)\leq v_{p}((p-1)^n+1)=v_{p}(n)+v_{p}(p)=v_{p}(n)+1$$(by Lifting-the-exponent lemma)

So $p=3$, $v_{p}(n)=1$. Then we have $n^2\mid 2^n+1$.

If $n=3$, $9\mid 9$. So $(p,n)=(3,3)$ meets the requirement.

If $n>3$, let $n=3m$, $3\nmid m$. So $m^2\mid 2^{3m}+1$.

Let r be the smallest prime factor of a. Similarly, we have $$r\mid 8^{2m}-1, r\mid 8^{r-1}-1$$

So $r\mid 8^{gcd(2m,r-1)}$, then we have $r=7$.

However, $8^m+1\equiv 2(mod 7)$.There exist a contradiction.

In conclusion, $(p,n)=(2,1),(2,2),(3,3)$.

Comment: Your solution is great! I haven't think about solve this problem by defining q as a the smallest prime factor.